# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EnvDTE.Project'

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-sdk

I am in the process of creating Azure Resource Manager deployment templates for my project using the Azure Resource Group Project in Visual Studio 2015 project templates. I successfully managed to create the projects before. But today, I updated the Azure SDK to v2.9.5 and suddenly the project creation failed. It failed with the following error message.

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'EnvDTE.Project'. This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID
>   '866311E6-C887-9833-645F5B93F6F1}' failed due to the following error:
>   No cush interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NONINTERFACE)).

[image]

This exception happens when i select starting template from the template selection dialog box (I selected WebApp+SQL template. This fails for other templates as well). So after this the project is incomplete created.

I faced this same issue in 3 different PCs with Azure SDK v2.9.5 installed. Is this issue related to the SDK itself? Or how should i fix this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, it works without any issue after I updated to Azure SDK 2.9.5. The SDK should be fine.

Comment: But i tested this with 3 PCs, all freshly updated SDK v2.9.5 in all 3 PCs the same issue came up. This can not be a coincidence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have bug and are working on a fix.  In the meantime you can:

- remove the solution items from your solution
- add the new project
- add the solution items back

LMK if that doesn't fix it for you...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same issue when trying to create a new azure project for an existing application.

I was able to workaround the problem by creating a new project with a new solution and selecting the template I wanted. I then added the azure template project into my existing project without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Open 'cmd' with Administrator privileges,

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\dte80.olb"
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\dte80a.olb"
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\dte90.olb"
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\dte90a.olb"
```