# Can't open package manager console in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, package-manager-console, nuget-package-manager-console

I am learning asp .net from this udemy course [udemy_course_link](https://www.udemy.com/course/quick-introduction-to-aspnet-mvc-core-20/). Whenever I open package manager console in visual studio 2019, Following error comes :
[image: error_msg]

The error message is: **Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'EnvDTE80.DTE2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{2EE1E9FA-0AFE-4348-A89F-ED9CB45C99CF}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).**

I am new to visual studio. I found a similar question in StackOverflow but that didn't help.

Comment: Could you try the method in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40226793/9862794) ? If it didn't work for you, could you show the detailed steps to reproduce your error?

Comment: How to do that? I just installed visual studio and .net.